# Running Posgres query with PDO: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Trying to follow the example in http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php
and connecting with

```
$dbh = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=example;user=postgres');
```

and running query

```
foreach ($dbh->query('SELECT * from Animals') as $row) {
  print $row;
}
```

I am getting the error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/zaitsev/tests/pg-php/pdo-test.php on line 13

What is wrong here?

Comment: @JayBlanchard No, you don't, it's even written in a manual. As for this case - obviously `query()` returns `false` instead of pdo statement.

Comment: Yikes @u_mulder - that just seems a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php#refsect1-pdo.query-returnvalues):

```
PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.
```

It's very probable that your query is returning `false` by some failure. Ensure your PostgreSQL connection and try out execute your query directly on PostgreSQL (PGAdmin).